# Search for variable content in array list

Tags: php

I have 4 strings with numbers like this:

```
$num1 = 0;
$num2 = 3;
$num3 = 3;
$num4 = 0;
```

Then I get the higher number:

```
$higher = max($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4);
```

So I get "$higher = 3"

Then I create an array with the owner of the number and the number itself like this:

```
$arr = array("user1" => $num1, "user2" => $num2, "user3" => $num3, "user4" => $num4);
```

Now my issue:

I would like to search my array $arr for the value $higher (3 in this case) and get the "user2" and "user3" as return.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) to search an array by value and get the associated key.

```
$key = array_search($higher,$arr);
```